# Build XML for a HashMap<String, Object>

Tags: java, xml, web-services, asp-classic, hashmap

I have a classic ASP page (VBScript) calling a Java Webservice and I am building the XML myself.  I'm not an expert at XML and am having trouble building a HashMap.  Whenever I send the XML to the service, the map does not get populated with anything.  This is currently what I have:

My Object:

```
public class QueryParameter {

    private String parameterType = "";
    private String parameterValue = "";

    public String getParameterType() {
          return parameterType;
    }
    public void setParameterType(String parameterType) {
          this.parameterType = parameterType;
    }
    public String getParameterValue() { 
          return parameterValue;
    }
    public void setParameterValue(String parameterValue) {
          this.parameterValue = parameterValue;
    }
}
```

My XML:

```
<queryParameters>
  <entry>
    <key>1</key>
    <value>
      <QueryParameter>
         <parameterType>String</parameterType>
         <parameterValue>this is a parameter</parameterValue>
      </QueryParameter>
    </value>
  </entry>
</queryParameters>
```

I'm assuming my XML is incorrect and that is why the parameter is set as an empty Map when the request gets to the web service.  Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you!

**EDIT:**

After loading the service wsdl into soapUI and viewing the call generated from there, I noticed that soapUI didn't know how to format the XML for the HashMap either.  Perhaps I was implementing it incorrectly from my service.

I modified my service to use an ArrayList instead of a HashMap and am able to generate the XML for an ArrayList successfully.  This will work for my problem, but if someone knows why I was unable to implement a HashMap, I would be curious to know the answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You set the content type of the response to `"text/xml"`?

```
<% response.ContentType="text/xml" %>
```

**Edit:**

Look if this link help you.

[Utilizing the Dictionary Object](https://web.archive.org/web/20210619173138/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/102898-1.shtml)

Comment: The above XML is being built on the ASP Classic page and sent to the Java Webservice in the request.  The response isn't my problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I believe the problem is in the java web service and being unable to use a Map as a parameter.  This article also describes the problem:
https://community.jboss.org/thread/101979?tstart=0

I have gone around this by using a List<object> where the object has a key and value.